# String could not be parsed as XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Tengo el siguiente trozo de código:

```
$f = fopen("../LB/1.1.1.1.xml", "w");
$resposta = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('php://input'));
fwrite($f, $resposta->asXML());
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in....

¿ Alguien sabe porque me sale el error ?

Gracias.

He realizado los siguientes cambios:

```
$a = fopen("../LB/1.1.1.1.xml", "r"); var_export($a); print("<br />"); echo get_resource_type($a); print("Exemple amb el nom del fitxer"); echo stream_get_contents($a); print("<br />"); var_dump((file_get_contents('php://input'))); $resposta = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('php://input')); print("<p> El valor de la variable resposta </p>"); echo stream_get_contents($resposta); fwrite($a, $resposta->asXML()); /* El método asXML formatea los datos del objeto */
```

El var_export($a); me indica que es NULL.

Con el echo get_resource_type($a); me dice que es un stream

Con el echo stream_get_contents($a); me enseña la información que hay dentro del XML.

El var_dump((file_get_contents('php://input'))); me devuelve string(0) "".

I es aquí donde me quedo bloqueado y no veo por donde seguir.

¿ Alguien se le ocurre alguna idea ?

Gracias.

Comment: esto ocurre porque `file_get_contents('php://input')` esta devolviendo un string que no es compatible para ser convertido o inicializado como `new SimpleXMLElement()`

Comment: entonces si no muestra en contendo de `file_get_contents('php://input')` no podemos ayudarte; puedes obtener eso con `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Comment: Prueba
```
$new_xml = mb_convert_encoding($comprobante->result->xml, 'UTF-8', mb_list_encodings());
```